# Problemas al trabajar con Clases PHP

Tags: php, poo, web

Estoy trabajando con clases en php y me da el siguiente error `Deprecated: Non-static method EnlacesModels::EnlacesModel() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/u430635434/public_html/travel-app/controllers/enlaces.php on line 15` trabajando en local no ocurre pero cuando lo subo al hosting, me pasa eso.

revisando la linea 15 del codigo tengo lo siguiente:

```
$respuesta = EnlacesModels::enlacesModel($enlaces);
```

Comment: Desde PHP 5.6.x no puedes llamar un método no estático, o sea, usando `::`,  como si fuera estático ([ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/migration56.deprecated.php)). El mensaje no aparece en tu entorno local porque seguramente tiene una versión de PHP anterior a `5.6.x`, mientras que la versión del hosting sí es `+5.6.x`. Hay varias formas de evitar esa situación... pero la más coherente sería, **declarar al método `enlacesModel` como `static` en la clase `EnlacesModels`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde PHP 5.6.x no puedes llamar un método no estático, o sea, usando `::`, como si fuera estático, sin tener la advertencia que indicas en tu pregunta ([ver Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/migration56.deprecated.php)).

El mensaje no aparece en tu entorno local porque seguramente tienes una versión de PHP anterior a `5.6.x`, mientras que la versión del hosting sí es `+5.6.x`.

Se trata de uno de los cambios relativamente recientes de PHP para corregir algo que era en realidad una *irregularidad*: **tratar a un método no estático como estático**.

Hay varias formas de evitar esa situación... pero la más coherente sería, declarar al método `enlacesModel` como `static` en la clase `EnlacesModels` si quieres seguir usándolo de este modo: `EnlacesModels::enlacesModels`. Eso suponiendo que ya tienes clara la finalidad de un método estático. Si ese aspecto no está claro, te aconsejo que leas [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php) e investigues sobre métodos estáticos en POO.

No recomendaría en ningún caso que trates de evadir el mensaje *haciendo trampa* :) , como por ejemplo evitando los mensajes de advertencia. Es muy probable que en futuras versiones de PHP esta situación pase de advertencia a error grave. Entonces podrías estar escribiendo un código que fallará a posteriori.

De este modo tu problema debería resolverse:

```
class EnlacesModels {

//...

    public static function enlacesModel($enlaces) {

        //...

    }

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo por responder, antes de ver tu respuesta habia conseguido una solucion. hice lo siguiente `class EnlacesControllers extends EnlacesModels { $this->enlacesmodel() }` que recomiendas?

Comment: También podría ser válido @Avancini1, aunque cuando se extiende una clase de otra puede haber un error no tanto de sintaxis sino de lógica o de diseño (no es perceptible porque el programa quizá no falle), pero podrías estar escribiendo un código que a la larga se hará confuso y difícil de mantener. No digo que sea tu caso o que no se deba usar la herencia de clases, lo que digo es que hay que saber usarla. Recomiendo que leas sobre el tema, [empezando por aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php), para no hacer uso de algo sólo por que sí, sino a conciencia. Saludos.