# Error de lectura de token

Tags: php, codeigniter, servidor, mariadb

les comento un poco mi problema, he tenido una sitio web hecho en codeigniter en un servidor y lo he pasado a otro servidor ambos contienen cpanel.
Creé la db en el otro tal y cual la importé y bueno todo bien en la parte del sitio web, sin embargo tengo un lado backend que me permite insertar nuevos post dentro de la página como un pequeño cms. El problema que tengo en sí es que no me está leyendo el token al parecer, adjunto algunas capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTA ES MI CLASE MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public $chat = TRUE; // Validar el Chat de Comunicación.
public $usuarios = array();
public $locked = FALSE; // Para ver si la sesión está bloqueada.
public $title = NULL; // Titulo del Controlador.
public $table = NULL; // Tabla definida de Consulta.
public $retorno = TRUE; // Retorno de Valores en el Formulario y en las Tablas.
public $items = array(); // Items de los Formularios y de las Tablas.
public $buttons = array(); // Botones de los Formularios y de las Tablas.
public $import = FALSE; // Para importar registros..
public $export = FALSE; // Para exportar registros..
public $publish = FALSE; // Si los registros son publicables.
public $status = TRUE;
public $order = FALSE;
public $type = 'table';
public $route = "uploads/";
public $where = array();
public $tamanio_disco = 0;
public $elementos_adicionales = array();
public $readonly = FALSE;
public $campo_referencia = 'id';
public $help = NULL;
public $sidebar = TRUE;
public $url_retorno = NULL;
public $per_page = 30;
public $nuevo_token = FALSE;
public $error = NULL;
public $breadcrumb = TRUE;
public $controller = NULL; // Controlador donde estamos trabajando.
public $parent_key = 'id';
public $item_order = array('key' => 'id', 'value' => 'desc');
public $show_order = array('key' => 'activado', 'value' => 1);
public $permisos = array();
public $menu = array();
public $session_name = "website";
public $configuracion = array();
public $alias = FALSE;
public $actions = array();
public $items_unlocked = array();
public $tipo_usuarios = array("Administrador Padre", "Administrador General");

// Funciones Básicas..

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    //print_r($_SESSION[$this->session_name]); die;

    // Idiomas..
    $language = (isset($_SESSION['language'])) ? $_SESSION['language'] : 'espanol';

    $directorio = dir('system/language/'.$language);
    
    while ($archivo = $directorio->read())
    {
        if($archivo != 'index.html' && $archivo != '' && $archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..')
        {
            $this->lang->load(str_replace('_lang.php', '', $archivo), $language);
        }
    }

    $this->config->set_item('language', $language);
    // Fin de los Idiomas..

    // Buscar los tipos de cambio..

    $this->load->model('module_model');

    // Generando un Token de Acceso..
    $token = $this->mostrar_session('token'); // Si es que ya existe un Token que no se ha usado..
    if(empty($token))
    {
        $token = $this->encrypt->sha1(uniqid(rand()));
        $this->cargar_session('token', $token);
    }

    /*
    if(current_url() == base_url().'backend' && !isset($_GET['token']))
    {
        redirect('backend?token='.$token);
    }

    elseif(strpos(current_url(), 'backend'))
    {
        if((isset($_REQUEST['token']) && $_REQUEST['token'] == $token))
        {
            $token = $this->encrypt->sha1(uniqid(rand()));
            $this->cargar_session('token', $token);
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($token);
            print_r($this->lang->line('token_error')); die;
        }
    }
    */

    if($this->input->is_ajax_request() !== TRUE)
    {
        $this->configuracion = $this->module_model->seleccionar('configuracion', array(), 1, 1);

        $config['item_order'] = array('key' => 'orden', 'value' => 'ASC');
        $this->initialize($config);
        $this->menu = $this->module_model->seleccionar('backend_menu', array('estado' => 1)); $grupo = array();

        $this->clear_data(); // Limpiamos la Información..
    }

    // Guardando un archivo de Logs por Administrador..
    if(self::mostrar_session('nivel') != 0 && self::mostrar_session('nivel') != NULL && $this->input->is_ajax_request() === TRUE)
    {
        $this->module_model->guardar('log_administrador', array('id' => '', 'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(), 'accion' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'ruta' => current_url(), 'usuario' => self::mostrar_session('id'), 'fecha' => $this->fecha()));
    }

    //print_r($_SESSION[$this->session_name]['miga_pan']); die;
    // Final del archivo de Logs..
}

function cargar_datos($post = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0)
    {
        $tabla = $this->input->post('id_padre');
    }
    else
    {
        $tabla = $post['id_padre'];
    }
    
    $where['estado'] = 1;

    if($tabla == 'institucional')
    {
        $tabla = 'institucional'; $where['tipo_padre'] = 1; $where['id_padre'] = 0;
    }
    if($tabla == 'padres')
    {
        $tabla = 'institucional'; $where['tipo_padre'] = 2; $where['id_padre'] = 0;
    }
    if($tabla == 'servicios')
    {
        $tabla = 'institucional'; $where['tipo_padre'] = 3; $where['id_padre'] = 0;
    }

    if($tabla == 'iconos_pequenios')
    {
        $tabla = 'iconos'; $where['id_padre'] = 1;
    }
    if($tabla == 'iconos_grandes')
    {
        $tabla = 'iconos'; $where['id_padre'] = 2;
    }

    if($tabla == 'banner_programas')
    {
        $tabla = 'banners'; $where['id_padre'] = 1;
    }
    if($tabla == 'banner_comunicados')
    {
        $tabla == 'banners'; $where['id_padre'] = 2;
    }
    if($tabla == 'banner_campanias')
    {
        $tabla == 'banners'; $where['id_padre'] = 3;
    }

    $data['values'] = $this->module_model->seleccionar($tabla, $where);
    $data['id'] = 'id'; $data['valor'] = 'titulo';

    if($return == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view("backend/templates/select_view", $data);
    }
    else
    {
        return $data['values'];
    }
}

/**
* @since 2014
* @author Luis Shepherd
* @method Iconos
**/

function mostrar_iconos()
{
    $array = array();

    $items = array('fa-rub', 'fa-pagelines', 'fa-stack-exchange', 'fa-arrow-circle-o-right', 'fa-arrow-circle-o-left', 'fa-caret-square-o-left', 'fa-dot-circle-o', 'fa-wheelchair', 'fa-vimeo-square', 'fa-try', 'fa-plus-square-o', 'fa-adjust', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-archive', 'fa-arrows', 'fa-arrows-h', 'fa-arrows-v', 'fa-asterisk', 'fa-ban', 'fa-bar-chart-o', 'fa-barcode', 'fa-bars', 'fa-beer', 'fa-bell', 'fa-bell-o', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-book', 'fa-bookmark', 'fa-bookmark-o', 'fa-briefcase');

    foreach($items as $key => $value)
    {
        $array[trim($value)] = '<span class="fa '.trim($value).' tooltips" title="'.trim($value).'"></span>';
    }       

    return $array;
}

/**
* @since 2014
* @author Luis Shepherd
* @method Recursividad | Sidebar..
**/

function recursividad($array = array(), $indice = NULL, $anterior = FALSE)
{
    $nuevo_array = ($anterior === FALSE) ? $array : array();

    if(count($array) > 0)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            $config['item_order'] = array('key' => 'orden', 'value' => 'ASC');
            $this->initialize($config);

            $resultado = $this->module_model->seleccionar('institucional', array('id_padre' => $value[$indice], 'estado' => 1, 'activado' => 1, 'menu' => 1));

            $nuevo_array[$value[$indice]] = $resultado;

            if(count($value) > 0)
            {
                $this->recursividad($resultado, $indice, TRUE);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $nuevo_array;
}

function buscar_elemento_sidebar($id = FALSE, $tipo = FALSE, $url = FALSE)
{
    $config['order'] = array('key' => 'orden', 'value' => 'asc');
    $this->initialize($config);

    $data['elementos'] = $this->module_model->seleccionar('institucional', array('id_padre' => $id, 'tipo_padre' => $tipo, 'estado' => 1, 'activado' => 1));

    $html = '';
    if(count($data['elementos']) > 0)
    {
        $html .= '<ul>';
        foreach($data['elementos'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $type = ($value['tipo_padre'] == 1) ? 'institucional' : (($value['tipo_padre'] == 2) ? 'padres' : 'servicios');

            $html .= '<li class="';
            if(current_url() == base_url().$type.'/'.$value['alias'].'/'.$value['id'])
            {
                $html .= 'active';
            }
            $html .= ($key == count($data['elementos']) - 1) ? ' last' : NULL;
            $html .= '">';
            $html .= '<a ';
            if($value['tipo'] == 2)
            {
                if($value['destino'] != '')
                {
                    $html .= 'target="'.$value['destino'].'" ';
                }
            }

            $html .= 'href="'.base_url().$type.'/'.$value['alias'].'/'.$value['id'].'">';
            $html .= '<span>'.$value['titulo'].'</span>';
            $html .= '</a>';
            /*
            if($value['tipo'] == '0')
            {
                $html .= self::buscar_elemento_sidebar($value['id'], $value['tipo_padre']); // recursividad
            }
            */
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $html;
}

function mostrar_menu()
{
    $array = array(); $grupo = array();

    if(self::mostrar_session('nivel') == 3 || self::mostrar_session('nivel') == 4)
    {
        $permiso_transparencia = $this->module_model->seleccionar('permisos', array('id_padre' => self::mostrar_session('id'), 'controlador' => 'transparencia', 'estado' => 1), 1, 1);
        $permiso_transparencia['url'] = 'transparencia';
        $permiso_transparencia['grupo'] = 'transparencia';
        $permiso_transparencia['icono'] = 'th-list';

        $this->menu[] = $permiso_transparencia;
    }
    
    foreach($this->menu as $key => $value)
    {
        $tipo_permisos = array('add' => 'add', 'update' => 'update', 'delete' => 'delete', 'all' => 'all', 'view' => 'view');

        if(self::mostrar_session('nivel') == 0 || self::mostrar_session('nivel') == 1) // Administradores
        {
            $array[$value['url']] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $permiso = $this->module_model->seleccionar('permisos', array('id_padre' => self::mostrar_session('id'), 'controlador' => $value['url'], 'estado' => 1), 1, 1);

            if(count($permiso) > 0)
            {
                $explode_permiso = explode('-', $permiso['acciones']);

                if($permiso['items'] != '')
                {
                    $items_unlocked = explode("-", $permiso['items']); // Items Unlocked

                    foreach($items_unlocked as $k => $v)
                    {
                        $this->items_unlocked[$value['url']][] = $v;
                        #$data['items_unlocked'][$value] = TRUE;
                    }
                }

                foreach($explode_permiso as $k => $v)
                {
                    if($v == 'view')
                    {
                        $_SESSION['view'] = array($this->controller => TRUE);
                    }

                    $array[$value['url']] = $value;
                    $this->permisos[$value['url']][$tipo_permisos[$v]] = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Creación de los Grupos..
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $grupo[$value['grupo']][] = $value;
    }
    // Fin de la Creación de los Grupos..

    return $grupo;
}

protected function retornar_menu($controlador = FALSE)
{
    $menu = NULL;
    foreach($this->menu as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value['url'] == $controlador)
        {
            $menu = $value['id'];
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}

protected function cargar_miga_pan($titulo = NULL, $metodo = FALSE)
{
    $continuar = TRUE; $anterior = current_url(); $nueva_session = array();
    
    $session = $this->mostrar_session('miga_pan');

    // Elementos Existentes..
    if(count($session) > 0)
    {
        foreach($session as $key => $value)
        {
            if(isset($value['link']) && $value['link'] != $anterior && $value['link'] != current_url() && $continuar === TRUE)
            {
                $nueva_session[] = $value;
                $anterior = $value['link'];
            }
            else
            {
                $continuar = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    // Elementos Existentes..

    if($metodo !== FALSE)
    {
        if($this->controller != $anterior)
        {
            $nueva_session[] = array('link' => $this->controller, 'texto' => $titulo, 'metodo' => 'abrir');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(current_url() != $anterior)
        {
            $nueva_session[] = array('link' => current_url(), 'texto' => $titulo);
        }
    }

    $session[$_REQUEST['parent']] = $nueva_session;

    //print_r($session); die;

    $this->cargar_session('miga_pan', $session);
}

function limpiar_texto($url)
{
    $find = array('á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'ñ');
    $repl = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'n');
    $url = str_replace ($find, $repl, $url);

    $find = array('Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú', 'Ñ');
    $repl = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'n');
    $url = str_replace ($find, $repl, $url);

    $url = strtolower($url);
    
    $find = array(' ', '&', '\r\n', '\n', '+');
    $url = str_replace ($find, '-', $url);
    $find = array('/[^a-z0-9\-<>]/', '/[\-]+/', '/<[^>]*>/');

    $repl = array('', '-', '');
    $url = preg_replace ($find, $repl, $url);

    return $url;
}

protected function validar_usuario()
{
    $response = array();
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request() === TRUE && isset($_GET) && count($_GET) > 0) // Si la consulta proviene de una petición AJAX
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION[$this->session_name]['correo_electronico']))
        {
            $response['url'] = backend_url();
            $this->load->view("backend/templates/redirect_view", $response);
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION[$this->session_name]['correo_electronico']))
        {
            redirect("backend", "refresh");
        }
    }
}

protected function cerrar_session()
{
    $this->module_model->actualizar('administrador', array('userlist' => 0), $this->mostrar_session('id'));

    foreach($_SESSION[$this->session_name] as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
    }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    
    redirect("backend", "refresh");
}

protected function identificarse($correo_electronico = NULL)
{
    $this->db->where("estado", 1);
    $this->db->where("activado", 1);
    $this->db->where("correo_electronico", $correo_electronico);
    $query = $this->db->get("administrador");
    $busqueda = $query->row_array();

    $data = array("correo_electronico" => $correo_electronico); // response

    if(count($busqueda) > 0) // identity
    {
        if($busqueda["contrasenia"] === $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post("contrasenia")))
        {
            // Guardando la variable en una COOKIE para poder bloquear la aplicación.

            $this->module_model->actualizar('administrador', array('userlist' => 1), $busqueda['id']);
            $this->cargar_cookie('correo_electronico', $busqueda['correo_electronico']);
            $this->cargar_cookie('usuario', $busqueda['nombres'].' '.$busqueda['apellidos']);
            $this->cargar_cookie('imagen', $busqueda['imagen']);

            foreach($busqueda as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key <> 'contrasenia')
                {
                    $this->cargar_session($key, $value);
                }
            }

            redirect(backend_url(), "refresh");
        }
        else
        {
            $data['message'] = "Contraseña no coincide.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Eliminar las cookies..
        delete_cookie($this->session_name);
        $data['message'] = "El usuario no existe.";
    }

    $this->load->view("backend/index_view", $data);
}

protected function cargar_session($key, $value)
{
    $array = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION[$this->session_name]))
    {
        $array = $_SESSION[$this->session_name];
    }

    $array[$key] = $value;

    $this->session->set_userdata($this->session_name, $array);
}

protected function descargar_session($key)
{
    $array = array();
    foreach($_SESSION[$this->session_name] as $k => $v)
    {
        if($k != $key)
        {
            $array[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata($this->session_name, $array);
}

function mostrar_session($key)
{
    $retorno = NULL;
    if(isset($_SESSION[$this->session_name]) && isset($_SESSION[$this->session_name][$key]))
    {
        $retorno = $_SESSION[$this->session_name][$key];
    }

    if($key == 'miga_pan')
    {
        if(isset($retorno[$_REQUEST['parent']]))
        {
            $retorno = $retorno[$_REQUEST['parent']];
        }
    }

    return $retorno;
}

protected function cargar_cookie($key, $value)
{
    /*
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$this->session_name]))
    {
        $array = $_COOKIE[$this->session_name];
    }
    $array[$key] = $value;

    setcookie($this->session, $array);
    */
}

protected function mostrar_cookie($key)
{
    //return $_COOKIE[$this->session_name][$key];
}

protected function check_default($array)
{
    if(count($array) > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }       
}

protected function validar_formulario($id = NULL)
{
    // Validaciones por Código..
    $config = array(); $validacion = FALSE; $busqueda = array();

    if($id != NULL)
    {
        $busqueda = $this->module_model->seleccionar($this->table, array('id' => $id), 1, 1);
    }

    foreach($this->items as $key => $value)
    {
        $required = NULL;

        if($value['type'] != 'multiple_select' && $value['type'] != 'photo' && $value['type'] != 'file')
        {
            if(isset($value['required']) && $value['required'] !== NULL && $value['type'] != 'password')
            {
                $required = 'trim|required';

                if(is_array($value['required']))
                {
                    foreach($value['required'] as $k => $v)
                    {
                        if($v == 'is_unique')
                        {
                            if($id == NULL)
                            {
                                $required .= '|'.$v;
                                $required .= '['.$this->table.'.'.$key.']';
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(strrpos($v, 'dateRange') != FALSE || strrpos($v, 'future') != FALSE || strpos($v, 'past') != FALSE)
                            {
                                $required .= '|'.$v;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if($value['type'] == 'multiple_select' || $value['type'] == 'group_checkbox')
        {
            if(isset($value['required']) && $value['required'] !== NULL)
            {
                $required = 'required|callback_check_default';
            }
        }
        
        if($value['type'] == 'photo' || $value['type'] == 'file')
        {
            if(isset($value['required']) && $value['required'] !== NULL)
            {
                if(count($busqueda) > 0)
                {
                    if($busqueda[$key] != '' && $busqueda[$key] != NULL)
                    {
                        $required = NULL; // Si existen valores ya no es necesario el requerido.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if($_FILES[$key]['name'] == '')
                        {
                            $required = 'trim|required'; // Se necesita adjuntar uno nuevo.
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if($_FILES[$key]['name'] == '')
                    {
                        $required = 'trim|required'; // Se necesita adjuntar uno nuevo.
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $required = NULL;
            }
        }

        if($required != NULL)
        {
            $config[] = array('field' => $key, 'label' => $value['text'][$this->config->item('language')], 'rules' => $required);
        }
    }

    if(count($config) > 0)
    {
        $validacion = TRUE; $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
    }
    // Fin de las Validaciones por Código..

    return $validacion;
}

        if(count($config) > 0)
        {
            $validacion = TRUE; $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        }
        // Fin de las Validaciones por Código..

        return $validacion;
    }
```

y donde estoy llamando a esa función es el archivo vista donde se encuentra el formulario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133244/discussion-on-question-by-renzo-error-de-lectura-de-token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error ocurre porque estás intentando llamar de forma estática a un método que no es estático aquí:

```
MY_Controller::mostrar_session('token');
```

Esto era permitido en versiones anteriores de PHP ([ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142965/29967)) pero era totalmente irregular y empezó a controlarse desde PHP 5.6.X, hasta devenir lo que es en realidad (un error).

Hay dos formas de solucionar esto:

1. Crear una instancia de la clase y llamar al método desde esa instancia:

   ```
    $mController=new MY_Controller( ... );
    $mController->mostrar_session('token');
   ```

   Esto implicaría incluir o requerir el archivo de la clase donde vayas a crear la instancia (a no ser que uses autoloader).
2. Declarar el método como `static`:

   ```
    public static function mostrar_session ( ... ) {
        // ...
    }
   ```

   Entonces esta llamada será posible:

   ```
    MY_Controller::mostrar_session('token');
   ```

Para decidirte por una solución u otra, no uses como criterio *la facilidad*. Te recomiendo que te informes sobre la naturaleza de los métodos estáticos y una vez informado decidas lo que sea mejor.